# How to "autoplay" video unmuted on mobile using JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, video, jwplayer, playlist

I am using JWPlayer for my videos on my site. What I want to achieve is to autostart videos unmuted. I have autostart feature on but the videos start muted.

The thing is I have playlists which directly refreshes the page instead of changing the video (i have to work this way). Whenever the page changes, the video starts automatically but muted just as before.

Is there any trick that I can autoplay videos unmuted on mobile browsers?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `video.volume = 1`?

Comment: Yes, doesnt work :(

Comment: That's not possible on older OS, Browser combinations. You'll end up using huge gif files or change the implementation to play by tap

Comment: It also depends on type of video. More info in [this JWP article](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725)

Answer (score 1):

The limitation is related to HTML5 videos, not just the JWPlayer - for various reasons video autoplay on mobile devices has historically been limited or restricted.

This was typically to avoid excessive bandwidth charges for users and also to avoid annoying users by having a video or audio suddenly play unexpectedly for them.

The restrictions are different for different platforms but it is fair to say that most platforms have eased the restrictions in recent years and autoplay of muted video is often supported now. Autoplay of united videos on mobile devices is still generally not allowed.

You can see the summary of Webkits policies for iOS as an example here: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

There is a specific focus on the audio track - e.g.:

> - video elements will be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture if their source media contains no audio tracks.
> - video muted elements will also be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture.
> - If a video element gains an audio track or becomes un-muted without a user gesture, playback will pause.